# Swift gRPC program not found

Tags: swift, grpc

Hi i want to use swift gRPC and install in my mac, i already install with homebrew but can't generate the plugins.

The error message is

```
protoc-gen-swiftgrpc: program not found or is not executable
Please specify a program using absolute path or make sure the program is available in your PATH system variable
```

The truth is i don't know how to put edit and add PATH in my ~/bash_profile

When i check in my terminal with

```
which protoc-gen-swift
```

it return

> /opt/homebrew/bin/protoc-gen-swift

i already search the article but there is no swift solution in this problem. Please help me i'm desperate with it.

Comment: Take a look at this thread: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/791, it appears to be related.
Also, try to just export path directly: export PATH="${PATH}:/opt/homebrew/bin"

Comment: @SergiiTkachenko i should the "export" in ~/.bash_profile ?

Comment: While I'm late, and you found an answer, what I mean was is to just run the export command in your terminal. If it fixed the issue, the next step would've been added to your shell profile (~/.bash_profile or ~/.profile).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found my solution, i think when it comes to swift grpc is hard to find the right tutorial. The problem i have is when i called protoc to generate in my terminal it failed to generate even though i have my plugin install.

There is a typo in this tutorial [swift grpc](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/swift-grpc-577ce1a4d1b7)

I just change the command from this

> protoc --swiftgrpc_out=. MyProto.proto

to this

> protoc --grpc-swift_out=. MyProto.proto

Comment: This is it! Apparently there are 2 separate plugins for this?

Answer (score 1):

> There is a typo in this tutorial swift grpc

Actually it seems that it is not a typo, but just a **not-updated** tutorial.

There are 2 versions of Swift GPRC plugins:

- One of them is the old `protoc-gen-swiftgrpc` plugin.
- And the other one is the new `protoc-gen-grpc-swift` plugin.

You can see more details here: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-swift#versions

Some tutorials use the old one.

That is why it shows `program not found or is not executable` error.

And additional explanatory message below that error

> Please specify a program using absolute path or make sure the program is available in your PATH system variable

just makes it more difficult to notice, as it simply focuses on potential path issues.

So, to summarize, what you install and what you are trying to run are not the same plugin.